# Implementing a Circular Single Linked List using a scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, circular-list

This is a given activity where we should create a method for inserting a node and it uses a scanner for its input. So far, I can input 3 objects from the list but here comes the problem when I try to add another one:

It goes something like this: 1,2,3 and when I try to add another it goes to this 1,2,4 but want I want is this 1,2,3,4.

I deeply appreciate your help in advance.

Here is the main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MySinglyLinkedCircularListMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ListOverflowException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        MySinglyLinkedCircularList<Node> singlyLinkedCircularList = new MySinglyLinkedCircularList<>();

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("+---------------------------------------------------+");
            System.out.println("| Select the Number to be executed:                 |\n" +
                    "| 1) Insert an element                              |\n" +
                    "| 2) Delete an element from the list                |\n" +
                    "| 3) Get an element from the list                   |\n" +
                    "| 4) Search an element in the list                  |\n" +
                    "| 5) Number of elements in the list                 |\n" +
                    "| 6) Show the elements in the list                  |");
            System.out.print("+---------------------------------------------------+ \n");
            System.out.print("Input your choice: ");
            int intInput = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (intInput == 1) {
                singlyLinkedCircularList.insert(new Node(singlyLinkedCircularList));

            } else if (intInput == 2) {
                singlyLinkedCircularList.delete(new Node(singlyLinkedCircularList));
             

            } else if (intInput == 3) {
                singlyLinkedCircularList.getElement(new Node(singlyLinkedCircularList));

            } else if (intInput == 4) {
                singlyLinkedCircularList.search(new Node(singlyLinkedCircularList));

            } else if (intInput == 5){
                System.out.println("The current capacity of the single circular linked list is "
                        + singlyLinkedCircularList.getSize());

            } else if (intInput == 6) {
                singlyLinkedCircularList.showAllElements();
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the node class

```
public class Node<T> {
    T data;
    Node<T> next;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> node) {
        next = node;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }
}
```

Here's the class for the insert method

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MySinglyLinkedCircularList<E> implements MyList<E> {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size;
    Node<E> startNode;
    Node<E> endNode;

    public MySinglyLinkedCircularList() {
        size = 0;
        startNode = endNode = null;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void insert(E data) throws ListOverflowException {
        System.out.print("Input the element you want: ");
        data = (E) keyboard.next();

        Node<E> newNode = new Node(data);


        if (startNode == null) {
            startNode = endNode = newNode;
            startNode.next = startNode;
            size++;
            System.out.println("Element " + startNode.getData() + " has been stored in position "
                    + getSize() + " and is now referenced itself");

        } else {
            Node<E> addNode = endNode;

            for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
                addNode = addNode.getNext();
            }
            addNode.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = startNode;
            size++;
}
}
```

Here's the show elements method

```
public void showAllElements() {
        Node<E> showNode = startNode;
        int i = 0;

        System.out.print("Here are the current elements: ");
        while (i<getSize()) {
            System.out.print(showNode.getData() + " ");
            showNode = showNode.getNext();
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print(showNode.getData());
    }
```

Here's the interface

```
public interface MyList<E> {
    public int getSize();
    public void insert(E data) throws ListOverflowException;
    public E getElement(E data) throws NoSuchElementException; 
    public boolean delete(E data); // returns false if the data is not deleted in the list
    public boolean search(E data);
    public void showAllElements();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic:

```
public void insert(E data) throws ListOverflowException {
    System.out.print("Input the element you want: ");
    data = (E) keyboard.next();  // ***** here *****
```

Your method accepts an E data parameter, `insert(E data)` and yet promptly discards any result held by the parameter in the second line of the method, `data = (E) keyboard.next();`, replacing it with Scanner input that shouldn't even be there. The MySinglyLinkedCircularList class should *not* have a Scanner object, nor should it take user input, but rather should handle the circular list's logic, and that's it. It shouldn't even have println statements, except perhaps temporary println's that you may usind during creation for debugging purposes only. Keep all UI code (user interface code -- Scanner input and println statements) together in the UI class.

Note, that I don't know if this is the cause of your full error, and to check for that will require more intense debugging, debugging that I urge you to do more of yourself, since it is both your responsibility to debug first, and it is a necessary and useful skill that only gets better with use.  If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: It seems weirder than that.  The insert calls look like (removing the excessive variable names) `list.insert(new  Node(list))`.  Why the Node ctor needs to know the list that it will soon be inserted into is not clear.  Maybe it's for the best it's ignored.

Comment: @user16632363: Yes, you are right.  I have to admit to not pouring of the code in detail (there's too much code, and I have too little time), but if you want to post your own answer, or add to this community wiki answer, please do so.

Comment: This part smells wrong: `Node<E> addNode = endNode` followed by finding the position `for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++)`.   If we know the end node, we presumably append the next entry after the end. What's the iteration for?  And because we iterate starting at the end, if feels like there could be an off-by-one error in there. But I haven't  bothered to work it through, so this is not an answer.  (Ditto on too much code/too little time).

Comment: @user16632363: nor is my "answer" a complete answer, which is why I copped out and posted a community wiki. The OP really really needs to do more debugging first and appears to have come here much too prematurely.

Comment: I've also been thinking if should I use a scanner or just directly call the insert method to insert something. But I guess I should have asked my teacher about that.

Comment: The 'get input' does not belong in the code that implements the linked list. You want (as a general thing) to be able to use a linked list without it having to talk to a person.  The right place to ask what is to be put in the list is right there in `main` after the user has said he wants to insert something. "What do you want to insert?" belongs there.